# js - bug/unwanted behavior: array indexOf() function also looks within number itself

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array containing a list of UID's of the users that a (logged-in) person is allowed to see information about, for example [2,22,50]. This is the array "rechten".

To filter the information that this person is allowed to see i made a for loop going through every person (having an UID), and determining whether or not the logged in user can see it by using:

```
if(rechten.indexOf(factuur["VERKOPER_UID"]) != -1){
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

The problem is that this returns true not only for 2,22 and 50 (as desired) but also for 5 (as 5 is a part of 50).

I also tried using the function rechten.includes() instead of rechten.indexOf but without the desired result either.

What can i do to compare if "50" is in the array, but not "5"? Where am i going wrong with this?

edit:

```
 data = data.filter(function(klant){
    console.log(rechten);
    console.log((klant["VERKOPER_UID"]));
    console.log(rechten.indexOf((klant["VERKOPER_UID"])));
  console.log(typeof rechten);
 rechten = JSON.parse(rechten);
  console.log(typeof rechten);
 // if(rechten.includes(klant["VERKOPER_UID"])){
    if(rechten.indexOf((klant["VERKOPER_UID"])) != -1){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

console log:

```
[50]
1
-1
string 
object

script-klanten-overview-2.js?ver=4:172 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
    at ...
    at Array.filter (native)
    at prepareDataKlanten (...)
```

Comment: Seems `rechten` is a string literal, thus [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) is working not `includes` or `Array.prototype.indexOf()`. just recheck using `console.log(typeof rechten)`

Comment: How to solve this then? I'm relatively new to js but i do understand what the problem is more or less

Comment: Try `rechten  = JSON.parse(rechten )` to get JavaScript object before if block

Comment: typeof rechten was indeed string.  After parse function it becomes object, but get another error; Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined.

Comment: Show the exact code which you are using

Comment: i edited question with logs and implemented changes

Comment: Could you show your recthen string? P.S. No bug in js, anyway. ;)

Comment: By using indexOf(parseInt(..)) function i managed to fix the problem. Thank you all for helping me find out what the problem was. How to close this question?